# python extract all texts between the first and last curly brackets including other curly brackets in the middle of text

Tags: python, regex

I have the following **strings**:

```
str1 = """
{'name': 'apple', 'description': 'red {03} … bright'}, {'name': 'banana', 'description': 'yello {153} not fresh'}
"""
```

The desired output is a list having two elements as below:

```
["{'name': 'apple', 'description': 'red {03} … bright'}", "{'name': 'banana', 'description': 'yello {153} not fresh'}"]
```

I tried it with re.findall(r"{.*?}", str1) but I got the following result:

```
["{'name': 'apple', 'description': 'red {03}",
 "{'name': 'banana', 'description': 'yello {153}"]
```

It did not capture the texts after the curly brackets in the middle of the text. I want to **capture all the texts between the first and last curly brackets including other curly brackets in the middle of text** . Do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: This does not appear to be a [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), i.e. possible to describe with a regular expression. In specific, expressions of the form ``S = A* "{" S "}" A*`` (that is, balanced parentheses containing balanced parentheses) are not regular.

Comment: Be aware that for some *specific* input, it is possible to "cheat", e.g. to split on ``},\w{`` (the comma-whitespace separation between the records). However, this requires to know all possible adversarial inputs to avoid conflicts – e.g. it will not work for ``"{"name": 'ap}, {ple'}".

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide details on what input should *not* be split on. Ideally, clarify whether/why you (think you) have to use ``re.findall(r"...", str1)`` for this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could parse the string manually. Pushing opening braces onto a stack, and popping when you see a closing brace, and yielding everything in-between.

```
def parse(content):

    pairs = {
        "{": "}"
    }

    open_stack = []

    for index, char in enumerate(content):
        if char in pairs:
            open_stack.append((char, index))
        elif open_stack and pairs[open_stack[-1][0]] == char:
            popped = open_stack.pop()
            yield content[popped[1]:index+1]

content = "{'name': 'apple', 'description': 'red {03} … bright'}, {'name': 'banana', 'description': 'yello {153} not fresh'}"
print(list(parse(content)))
```

Output:

```
['{03}', "{'name': 'apple', 'description': 'red {03} … bright'}", '{153}', "{'name': 'banana', 'description': 'yello {153} not fresh'}"]
>>>
```

It's not ideal, though. As you can see, it also yields `{03}` and `{153}`. Using this solution, you would have to pick and choose those specific yielded substrings that you want - not a fan.

---

EDIT - @MisterMyagi has made the observation that, with a small change to the original code, the `parse` generator can yield the desired output:

```
def parse(content):

    pairs = {
        "{": "}"
    }

    open_stack = []

    for index, char in enumerate(content):
        if char in pairs:
            open_stack.append((char, index))
        elif open_stack and pairs[open_stack[-1][0]] == char:
            popped = open_stack.pop()
            if not open_stack:
                yield content[popped[1]:index+1]
```

Specifically, if the `open_stack` is empty after an item has been popped off of it, we know that we are not referring to a nested structure.

Output:

```
["{'name': 'apple', 'description': 'red {03} … bright'}", "{'name': 'banana', 'description': 'yello {153} not fresh'}"]
>>>
```

Comment: This code would work if it would only ``yield`` if the stack is empty after the ``.pop``.

Answer (score 0):

Try using curly brackets '()'  for numbes inside value,  something like:str1 = """
{'name': 'apple', 'description': 'red (03) … bright'}, {'name': 'banana', 'description': 'yello (153) not fresh'}
"""

Comment: Sorry I don't want to change any texts in this case

Answer (score 0):

`{.*?}(?!(?>[^',]*?'))`

`(?!(?>[^',]*?'))` : It accepts as one more character of the (quantifier) match a `}` character after which a single quote `'` appears.

(I'm sorry, maybe your python regex does not accept atomic groups?)